# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, null, uncaught-exception

I'm just a beginner trying to learn some AJAX so my question may be dumb. When I open this document in my browser, I click the button on the page and get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null". I've tried to fix this, and even removed the line with the innerHTML property and the same error involving innerHTML keeps showing up, how's that even possible? would appreciate some help.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function cargaXML(){

        var conexion;
        var txt,x,i;

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                        conexion = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else {
                        conexion = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }



        conexion.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (conexion.readyState == 4 && conexion.status == 200){
                xmlDoc = conexion.responseXML;
                txt = "<table>";
                x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("titulo");
                artista = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("artista");
                pais = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("pais");
                firma = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("firma");
                precio = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("precio");
                anio = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("anio");

                for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){
                    txt = txt + "<tr><td>" + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td><tr>" + artista[i].childNodes[0].nodevalue + "</td><td>" + pais[i].childNodes[0].nodevalue + "</td><td>" + firma[i].childNodes[0].nodevalue + "</td><td>" + precio[i].childNodes[0].nodevalue + "</td><td>" + anio[i].childNodes[0].nodevalue + "</td>";
                }
                txt = txt + "</table>";
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = txt;
            }

            conexion.open("GET","discos.xml",true);
            conexion.send();
        }

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Mi colección</h2>
    <div id="myDiv">



    </div>

    <button type="button" onclick="cargaXML()">Tomar mi colección</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the javascript is running before the div "myDiv" is printed to the page. Usually this is corrected by using jQuery and the $(document).ready call. In javascript, you could use the onload property on window:

window.onload = cargaXML;

Answer (score 0):

Try putting everything in the script tag just below the button because everything in the page loads in a logical order, so you have

- JavaScript
- HTML

It's trying to access the HTML tag before it's even rendered so it should go

- HTML
- JavaScript

or add a body onload around the whole script so it waits for the document to load before attempting to use it